# using HttpClient in WinForms: can I parse JSON result using similar model binding as found in Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, parameters, model-binding

I guess I'm trying to interact with Web API as if these were the days of SOAP web service xml.. where a WSDL-based proxy CLR object was produced after talking to the server via HTTP. I'm not looking forward to walking a JSON response using JSON.NET, but, will if I have to.

So.. as we all know (all of us ASP.NET web devs) - we can use the Web API (and Web API 2, etc) to simply POST some JSON to an api controller and model binding (err.. [parameter binding?](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)) is capable of parsing that into my preferred CLR object.

Let's say I now have a WinForms client that wants to interact with my fancy Web API server - and I presume I ought to talk to that Web API using an [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Is there a preferred way to interact with the Web API to get a CLR object out of it? I presume I'm going to get JSON out of it that I must then bind to a CLR object... and that is my main question.. how can I do the same instantiation of a CLR-from-JSON on my client that I see happening when I'm posting the JSON up to the server.

The key term I didn't think of when I first wrote this question is 'deserialize'.. now I'm finding results like [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(json);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731389/how-do-i-convert-a-complex-json-object-to-clr-object-with-json-net) and [`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Still curious if there's a preference out there

Comment: Just to see if I get it right. You want to know how can you convert a CLR to json and do a POST to your API, or is it how can you map a JSON response to a CLR object?

Comment: the latter.   since I see the Web API auto-magically binding JSON into CLR.. is there a way I can do that same thing to a piece of JSON outside of the web server pipeline.. so.. I know Model Binding takes into account routes and other bits that wouldn't be available in my client context.. but.. am still hoping there's a simple "reference this namespace" and "call this method" to get at what's already apparently there in the MVC / Web API stack

Comment: I'm unaware of such thing.. I would use JSON. NET but that's not what you want, right?

Comment: my experience with JSON.NET was that it was good for transforming JSON into a kind of dictionary keyed by strings... which made it easier to tease values out ..  but I'm looking for *a single method call* - where I can generically pass in my Type, and it does it's best to fill all the properties it can find of that Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (try to) read the response's content of HttpClient as any object.
Here is a sample method

```
public async Task<List<GroupListViewRow>> ListAccountGroupAsync(Guid ledgerId) {
        var response = await this.http.GetAsync($"v1/group/list?ledgerId={ledgerId}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<GroupListViewRow>>();
        return res;
    }
```

This one is reading the response as if it is `List<GroupListViewRow>`

Comment: ok, will try this out as I begin coding this part of my solution in the coming week. Keep in mind I am working inside a WInForms client, so I don't have the normal web application context available. (what `using` statements or dlls do I need to reference in my project for the code above to work?)

Comment: if you are using .net 4.5+ you have to reference System.Net.Http for older version get the nuget package Microsfto.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: my winForms is .NET 4.. going to try `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.20710`

Comment: This is using JSON.NET internally

Comment: I don't think I can do the `http.GetAsync` business without moving up to 4.5 framework.. Vis. Studio complaining about not finding a suitable GetAwaiter method. IDK if I'm in a position to upgrade the project to 4.5 yet